# The network path was not found (Working on Local System)some data adapter issue or sql server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008, localhost

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found
>
> Source Error:
>
> **Line 908:** this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[0];
> **Line 909:** DiseasesDal.DiseasesDataTable dataTable = new DiseasesDal.DiseasesDataTable();
> **Line 910:** this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
> **Line 911:** return dataTable;
> **Line 912:**        }

Comment: need more information. need to see more code. need to see the connection string to the database, filepaths which are referenced etc.

Comment: If you're using a disk-based db you may want to verify that it has the proper path as well as check connectionstrings.com to ensure it's referenced properly.

Comment: yes,,,everything is fine and running,,,whole code runs on other systems but not on mine...

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick please state it as answer.... i accepted my own answer(wrongly) which was based on your,,,please post your commen as answer....thanks